# How to compare two cluster solutions in graphs?

Tags: clustering, information-theory, graph-theory

I have two ways to cluster nodes in a given graph, and now I want to compare my two clusters so to measure how "similar" the resulting clusters are. I have found some measures of similarity (Rand index, Variation of information, etc), but none of them takes into account the structure of the graph.

So my question is if exist some measure that considers distances in the graph?

Comment: Can you paste in a simple example dataset / pair of cluster outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Measures like Rand index are based on pairs of points.

A pair of points is essentially an edge.

These measures are based on the agreement on which object should be 'linked' and which should *not* be 'linked', so I would call of this family of measures "graph based". And for sure they will work on graph  clusterings.